# Hard shutdowns and data corruption (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: hard-drive, backup, shutdown

Ok, so I run Ubuntu 20.10 on my laptop and things are generally fine. I have one compatibility issue that occurred after recent system updates (at least I think so). I don't know where the problem occurs exactly though. I plug my laptop to an external computer monitor, and I need to go through one of these small adapters that have additional ports so I can use an HDMI cable (I think it might be possible this adapter is damaged). Anyway, what happens is that I frequently have to do a hard shutdown of my laptop because both screens turn black. This often happens when I need to do a video call on my laptop directly, then close the screen and nothing happens on the external monitor. I open up the laptop again and it's all black. Sometimes I try disconnecting the adapter first, but I still get issues.

Other than being very annoying, I'm starting to be concerned about the data. I hear doing so can corrupt it. Now that we have to work from home, I much prefer to do my work on my computer rather than connect to my work computer through vpn. I recently backup my computer, but I'm afraid I could backup corrupted data. Is there an automatic way I can check for corrupted files? And fix them if possible? It would be a BIG problem if I end up loosing critical files. Or better, anyone knows what could be happening with my laptop/adapter?

Comment: Is it docking station what you you're talking about? I mean the 'adapter' ? It can possibly a driver issue but in order to figure out, you need to do something. Check if the machine has an HDMI port and connect the Monitor to the HDMI port. If the problem occurs, it's got something to do with External monitor or the driver present in Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, share which model of the machine you have and the monitor as well.

Comment: When "*both screens turn black*", have you tried other methods of restarting (R-E-I-S-U-B) or TTY? After a hard shutdown, do you run fsck?

Comment: My laptop is a HP Envy x360 15 (2020). The adapter is indeed a docking station, although it doesn't look like one, it is the HP Envy USB-C Hub. And the monitor is a Samsung LED monitor (S24F350FHU). The laptop doesn't have an HDMI port, that is why I bought the hub. I feel it might be an issue with Ubuntu. I also have problems with my external hard drive, it recognizes it, but I am unable to "safely remove" it, I get error messages.

Comment: Never heard of R-E-I-S-U-B or TTY, I will try them next time. fsck? Never tried either. I tried to run the command, it seems like I have to unmount the drive? I will look into that in more detail.

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot. I have a dual boot with Windows 10. I tried closing the lid and opening it up again in W10 and everything seems to work fine. It's probably a compatibility issue with Ubuntu I got after some update. I tried R-E-I-S-U-B although I'm not sure if I was pressing the right button for SysRq. That button is clearly written on my external keyboard, so I tried plugging it in my laptop, but the usual num light wouldn't be there. I tried the command anyway but nothing happened. Hopefully this will get fixed in another update as it's really bad right now. Thanks for the help!